# MVC 4 : Passing around user group data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am in the process of rewriting my PHP website in ASP.NET and writing the membership system.

I understand I can extend MembershipUser to add member specific properties but how can I pass around boolean group information such as *Use Search*, *Edit Posts* etc which are not user specific? Is there a framework item I am missing or should I just create a super object to pass this and other settings around?

Essentially what I want it an efficient way to access the users group properties in my controllers.

Comment: Please explain your way of accessing. Do you need to use Membership calls or are you willing to use the db?

Comment: Currently my member information and group information is in the DB and as a first stage I am not changing the DB (MySQL) but only the code PHP >> ASP.NET. There seems less and less advantage to fitting my solution into the MVC membership framework unless im missing something security related? I dont see any security benefits but only constraints which I would need to extend and then recast (eg MembershipUser). Looking for a robust solution to this, or at least be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I always create a users table with foreign key userID(GUID). I create a view (usersView) joining my users table and the aspnet_users table. Finally, I load the usersView into my EDMX file.

Comment: i dont think there is a need to have two tables (1) if you extend MembershipUser you can have your own table and (2) if you create something outside the framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from extending the `MembershipProvider`, you can also extend `RoleProvider`. RoleProvider is in charge of checking to which group a user belongs to, registering new roles, adding user to role(s), etc. To work with roles you will use Roles class which contains a lot of static methods.

In addition to this, each time you hit a Controller, you can query `HttpContext.User` property which implements `IPrincipal`. This property has method `IsInRole` that is used to communicate with RoleProvider to obtain information if a user is in specific group or not.

Also, in order to allow access to controllers or actions you can use `Authorization` attribute and list specific roles that have access to the controller.

The roles can be stored in a cookie (to cache them) or you can implement `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in **global.asax** and initialize `GenericPrincipal` manually. This object is passed over to HttpContext.User. The constructor of this object accepts an array of roles that are queried with IsInRole method.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if user is authenticated
    if (HttpContext.User != null)
    {
        // Extract roles from a cookie if you used FormsAuthentication
        // or read them from a cookie or from some other cached location

        // Split roles into array of strings
        var roles = listOfRoles.ToArray(); // If it is stored in a List<string>.
        var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity;
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);

        HttpContext.User = principal;
    }
}
```

The above code is not tested. I wrote it from top of my mind. It should give you a pretty good picture how to cache roles and to use them in the most efficient way.

**UPDATE**: In case that you need more advanced options where each role can have one or more functionality like your "Use search", "Can do something", "Can do that", I would implement the following security logic:

- Users
- Roles (users belong to roles)
- AccessRight (Role can have one or more access right).

UsersRoles table would be for adding users to specific roles.
RolesAccessRights table is where you define specific rights to each role.
User never talks to Functionality. (BTW, this naming convention is just an example, you will follow your naming conventions).

At my last work this is how we implemented the Audit system (it was Web Forms based). However, in MVC you could override `AuthorizationAttribute` to check user's role and to check if Role has defined access rights. Considering that you have specific security requirement, you would have to use this attribute on every action where you see the need and necessity.

If you plan to implement this logic, forget about Membership, MembershipUser and Roles. Honestly, I don't use these classes any more. I have my own custom security that I implement and which I used in the last 4 projects without any need for update or modification.

**UPDATE 2**: The security solution that we used was based on custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider. Thinking about it now, it was a mistake to rely on that because access to AccessLevel table had to be mapped via Entity Framework. Therefore we had to ways to query our security tables.

My suggestion to you would be to ignore Membership- and Role-related classes completely. The first reason is that you would avoid bothering yourself with unnecessary methods and properties when you override the providers. There would be too many methods with `throw new NotSupportedException()` in the method body.

## Suggested implementation

You will need the following tables:

1. **Users** - (You need at least three columns UserId, UserName, Password). If you want to hash the password, you might have to store salt as well. Other columns like FirstName, LastName, etc. I would suggest you to store in a different table and link it with UserId. As for UserId type it's up to you whether you would use `int` or `Guid`.
2. **Roles** - (You need at least two columns RoleId, RoleName). Again, as with UserId, it is up to you which data type you want to use.
3. **UsersRoles** - Store UserId and RoleId. You might want to store properties such as whether the role **IsActive** which is a bit value.
4. **AccessRights** - This is where you would store a key of your access right. In your case that is like *UseSearch*, *EditPosts*, *DeletePosts*, etc. Here you should use at least three columns AccessRightId, AccessRightKey and AccessRightDescription. This description field will turn to be pretty valuable if you have a lot of access right keys.
5. **RolesAccessRights** - This is where you define to which role you have added specific access rights. Also have **IsActive** bit value in order to disable the specific access right to a role.

In MVC you would override **AuthorizationAttribute**. In this attribute you would specify a list of access rights that have access to controller and/or actions. How you plan to do this is entirely up to you, but I would create an enum with a list of values that are the same as AccessRightsKeys. That way you can use strongly typed access rights instead of string based list. For more information about implementing custom authorization attribute have a look at the references list.

Inside of this attribute, you would read User ID and retrieve the roles. Compare the AccessRightsKeys that you specified against the roles (RolesAccessRights table) to see if the role has access right and whether the rule is active.

As for the solution based implementation I would implement Security service layer which communicates with Security-based repository and unit of work solutions. Because you are using MySQL I don't know which ORM you can use or would you have to rely on ADO.NET with OLEDB providers for MySQL.

My usual approach is a top-down approach. I implement from the high up (like Presentation layer) and go down towards data access layer. That way at the end I have only those methods which I really use and there is no redundancy.

Well, I hope this gives you some picture on how to this. As for time it takes, you can do this in about 8-10 hours.

Reference:

1. [Implementing a Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
2. [Roles Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx)
3. [How to: Create a Custom AuthorizationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

Comment: I have the above but the role is only a string and nothing more complex so I can only store a name there. But if each role needs further properties such as "can use search" how would this be stored? Its too general to extend MembershipUser and roles does not allow for anything more complex than a string. Would I need to pass around a settings object of some kind and then lookup the permissions in this or is there a way im not aware of using roles?

Comment: I am coming to this conclusion that really the framework will not bring any benefits. Your above *AccessRight* is not part of the framework but something custom? If so are there any benefits to using the framework apart from having a set structure and method calls relating to users?

Comment: AccessRight is a custom table. What .NET provides is pretty good for standard security operations, but from time to time you will have to create something completely custom. The above solution is not very hard or complex to implement. If you want I could elaborate on my answer to describe how we used it.

Comment: yes please, if you can elaborate. This will form the basis for my whole solution and so I want to ensure I go in the right direction.